# Validation in Form Returning False Form After Form Reset

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a form and a button with the name clear of type reset.
My form has some fields and some select, if I normally fill in the fields, and using the .valid () function from jquery it returns true normally.
but if I clear the form with the button with the type = "reset" the form always returns false in the jquery valid () function.

```
   <form id="myForm" class="form" role="form">


  <button href="#" class="btn btn-default"  type="reset"><i class="fa fa- 
  eraser"></i> Clear</button>
</form>

function search(){
 //after clearing the form ever return false
 if ($("#myForm").valid())
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

What is the right way to clean a form quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery way

```
$('#yourForm').trigger("reset");
```

or js way

```
document.getElementById("yourForm").reset();
```

Comment: in fact it worked but keeps appearing as validation messages required after cleaning

Comment: I want you to reset the fields without validating

Comment: what should I do?